# Change Login Button color in Keycloak Custom Login Theme

Tags: css, keycloak

I am customizing the login theme in keycloak. I am trying to change the color of the login button, but it does not reflect the color.
I tried the following in my css file.

```
#kc-login {
    background-color: rgb(2, 202, 102) !important;
}
```

But, it shows the new color only on hover.
It is a bootstrap primary button which is blue in color by default. I am not good in css. Anyone please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
background: none;
background-color: rgb(2, 202, 102) !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This
To change the login button color

```
input[type=submit] {       
     background-color: rgb(2, 202, 102) !important; 
}
```